# using datareader with dbnull values in .net4

Tags: .net, field, datareader, vb.net-2010, dbnull

I heard there is a field extension method in framework 4 that permits one to receive null values from a datareader, without having to go through the process of first testing if not null then ... etc.  There's information about the extension method here ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx)), but i don't know how to use it in code (am relatively new to .net and never used extension methods before).  Would appreciate if anyone can give an example.

This is what i tried to implement, but it returns an error when a dbnull is returned in either one of the columns.

```
Reader.Read()
Dim Val As Nullable(Of Double) = Reader.GetDecimal(0)
Dim Vol As Nullable(Of Long) = Reader.GetInt32(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Those extension methods relate to `DataRow` - i.e. `DataTable`... *not* `IDataReader` (etc).
You can do what you want here with a conditional, though - `IIf` in VB, or in C#:

```
double? val = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? (double?) null : reader.GetDouble(index);
long? vol = reader.IsDBNull(index) ? (long?)null : reader.GetInt64(index);
```

You could of course wrap those up as utility methods, perhaps as your own custom extension methods on `IDataReader`:

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    public static int? ReadNullableInt32(this IDataReader reader, int index)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(index) ? (int?)null : reader.GetInt32(index);
    }
    public static long? ReadNullableInt64(this IDataReader reader, int index)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(index) ? (long?)null : reader.GetInt64(index);
    }
    public static double? ReadNullableDouble(this IDataReader reader, int index)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(index) ? (double?)null : reader.GetDouble(index);
    }
    public static string ReadNullableString(this IDataReader reader, int index)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(index) ? null : reader.GetString(index);
    }
    // etc
}
```

(sorry for using c# for the examples - but you can probably read c# better than I can write *accurate* vb.net)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `DataRow` extension methods you need a `DataRow`. There is no method on a `DataReader`, so what you need to do is to load the reader into a `DataTable` (in C#):

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Load(reader);

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var value = row.Field<Decimal>(0);
}
```

It is important to realise that this is not logically equivalent to using the DataReader.Read() method as you will be loading the entire reader into memory when you load it into the `DataTable`. This may cause problems if your row set is large.