# Invalid Cast DateTime?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a class with the following code

```
 public cCase(string pCaseNo, string pMode)
    {
        if (pMode == "new")
        {
            this._caseNo = Validate_CaseNo(pCaseNo);
        }
        if (pMode == "existing")
        {
            try
            {
                int intValidatedCaseNo = Validate_CaseNo(pCaseNo);
                string sqlText = "SELECT * FROM tblCases WHERE CaseNo = @CaseNo;";
                string strConnection = cConnectionString.BuildConnectionString();
                SqlConnection linkToDB = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
                linkToDB.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sqlText, linkToDB);
                sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CaseNo", SqlDbType.Int);
                sqlCom.Parameters["@CaseNo"].Value = intValidatedCaseNo;
                SqlDataReader caseReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
                if (caseReader.HasRows)
                    while (caseReader.Read())
                    {
                        this._claimant = caseReader["Claimant"].ToString();
                        this._defendant = caseReader["Defendant"].ToString();
                        this._caseType = caseReader["CaseType"].ToString();
                        this._occupation = caseReader["Occupation"].ToString();
                        this._doa = (DateTime?)caseReader["DOA"];
                        this._dateClosed = (DateTime?)caseReader["DateClosed"];
                        this._dateSettled = (DateTime?)caseReader["DateSettled"];
                        this._dateInstructed = (DateTime?)caseReader["DateInstructed"];
                        this._status = caseReader["Status"].ToString();
                        this._instructionType = caseReader["InstructionType"].ToString();
                        this._feeEstimate = (decimal?)caseReader["FeeEstimate"];
                        this._amountClaimed = (decimal?)caseReader["AmountClaimed"];
                        this._amountSettled = (decimal?)caseReader["AmountSettled"];
                        this._caseManager = caseReader["CaseManager"].ToString();
                    }
                caseReader.Close();
                linkToDB.Close();
                linkToDB.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception eX)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error finding case" + Environment.NewLine + eX.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

However the Datetime? casts fail with an 'Invalid Cast'.
I've checked the SQL database and the field is storing valid dates
So I cant work out why, as I extract info via the DataReader into my app, the datetime fields are causing an Invalid Cast.

Please help.

Comment: What type does `caseReader` hold?

Comment: One of your DateTime fields probably holds a DBNull - as far as I know can you not directly cast from DBNull into a Nullable type. There are however extensions for this case.

Comment: As well as other answers regarding nulls - you say that the field is storing valid dates, but is it storing them using an appropriate data type (e.g. `datetime`, `datetime2` or `date`)?

Comment: Seems one of the datatype for dateTime field is VARCHAR(MAX) or NTEXT. Please check the type in SQL table, you may get some clue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're going to want to change the line that reads:

```
this._doa = (DateTime?)caseReader["DOA"];
```

to:

```
if (caseReader["DOA"] != DBNull.Value)
    this._doa.Value = (DateTime)caseReader["DOA"];
```

As well as all similar lines.

DBNull values cannot be casted from Nullable types.

Comment: tried this but it says DBNull is a type but it is used like a variable?!

Answer (score 4):

Your `DateTime` fields probably hold a `DBNull` value which you cannot convert directly.

However, I'd use an extension method on your `DataReader` for convinience.

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
  public static DateTime? ReadNullableDateTime(this IDataReader reader, string column)
    {
        return reader.IsDBNull(column) ? (DateTime?)null : reader.GetDateTime(column);
    }
}
```

// Usage

```
 this._dateInstructed = CaseReader.ReadNullableDateTime("DateInstructed");
```

Comment: The credits actually go to Mark, he's had the idea to wrap them in extensions http://stackoverflow.com/a/9464730/1028323

Comment: Thats because he's related to Chuck Norris.

Comment: You mean Jon Skeet? Because as far as I know, Chuck Norris can't cast a DBNull to a DateTime? While Jon clearly can.

Comment: upvoted. Note this is not the same as the if-then solution which would not assign anything to the variable if the database field was null, it would leave it alone. So ,if it already had a value that would perisst.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

[**DateTime.TryParse Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx)

this not throw exception, like

```
var mydate =(DateTime)datetimeString
```

or 
    var mydate =DateTime.Parse(datetimeString)

does!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code part

```
this._doa = (caseReader["DOA"] == DBNull.Value ? DBNull.Value : Convert.ToDateTime(caseReader["DOA"]);
```

Comment: Why convert the value to a string just to perform a null check?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I changed it. But there I checked not only the null values but also empty too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Convert Date Time as

```
this._doa = Convert.ToDateTime(caseReader["DOA"]);
```

Comment: If caseReader["DOA"] is DBNull.Value will give an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I often deal with `DBNull.Value`...

So I use this method that will return the value of the object or the default value of the given value type if object's value is `DBNull.Value`.

```
    public static object GetValueOrDefault(object value, Type type)
    {
        if (value != DBNull.Value)
            return value;

        if (type.IsValueType == false)
            return null;

        Array array = Array.CreateInstance(type, 1);

        return array.GetValue(0);
    }
```

Usage:

```
GetValueOrDefault(dataRecord.GetValue(fieldIndex), dataRecord.GetFieldType(fieldIndex)
```